# jQuery check contents of inputs match expression or string

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I'm wanting to create some very basic validation for a user login, it's not sensitive data.

I just want to check that the username and password are correct if they are process the form if they are not just unhide a paragraph of text that prompts the user to enter th correct details. Nothing more is required.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "correct" mean? That they are valid? That they are not empty? Or what else?

Comment: Remember, this is *not* a out-sourcing website, where a lot of guys with a bunch of free time sit around waiting to write code for people coming to the board :). Show us the code and we are happy to help.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried or http://jsfiddle.net/ it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable to use jquery to validate in front end as it will expose your data to clients. But if you really wants to , you can do the following.

```
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Submit").click(function(){
     if($("#txtUserName").val() == 'XYZ' && $("#txtPassword").val() == 'Password')
     {
        //do directing stuff
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

PS:Value validation should be done in server side scripting, regex validation can be done in client scripting.

Comment: Yes, client side validation can be totally bypassed, always. But you need to do both, client side to provide a better user experience, and server side to be sure that the input you get is actually validated and not just supposedly validated by the client.

Comment: Thanks man thats exactly what I wanted. In this case security isn't an issue at all.